# Difference between commands.Bot and interactions.Client

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, bots

I've been writing a discord bot for a week now and tried claiming *Discord Active Developer Badge* today. I was surprised, because I couldn't claim it - I checked requirements and my bot needed to execute **at least 1 command** this month - certainly I completed it already. I researched it a bit deeper, and it seems that discord encourages people to use **slash-commands** and not **prefix-based** commands as I did with my bot. Here's an example of it:

```
# Prefix based
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

permissions = discord.Intents()
permissions.message_content = True
permissions.messages = True
permissions.reactions = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", intents=permissions)

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx: commands.Context):
    await ctx.send("Registered!")

bot.run(TOKEN_HERE)
```

After a good amount of time, I couldn't figure out how to create **slash commands** using regular discord libraries, but I found an "[Interactions](https://discord-interactions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html)" library, with which, I could define a so called command schema and do something with it. Here's an example:

```
# Slash based
import discord
import interactions

bot = interactions.Client(TOKEN_HERE)
@bot.command(
    name="testing",
    description="testing_command!"
)
async def test(ctx: interactions.CommandContext):
    await ctx.send("Registered!")

bot.start()
```

This is considered **slash command**, it even creates a helping information in the discord itself:
[image: example]

The question is, should I continue developing with `commands.Bot` bot or switch to the `interactions` library and learn it instead? Can I migrate my currently existing bot somehow or add a so-called schema without using interactions library?

It's just annoying that I found out about it when I'm already really familiar with regular `discord` library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `discord` library does have in-built slash commands with [app_commands.CommandTree](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.CommandTree). Here's an example of that

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Ready')

client = MyClient(intents=discord.Intents.default())
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@tree.command(name='mycommand')
async def mycommand(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message('Hello World!')
    # Important to note the difference between Interaction and InteractionResponse
```

### Is it better to develop with slash commands?

Short answer: Yes

Long answer: Slash commands are more versatile than normal prefix commands. Although typing out prefix commands is faster and more convenient, the advantages of slash commands outweigh that of prefix commands. Discord would also be more focused on developing the library with slash commands than prefix commands so you would expect more features to be catered towards slash commands in the future.

Useful features of slash commands include, limiting user input, better handling of input arguments, and much more.

### Interactions vs Discord

I've personally never used the `interactions` library and stuck with `discord`. However, looking at your code example, it seems like an easy way to convert prefix commands to slash commands.

From the documentation of [Interactions](https://discord-interactions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) library

> Even if it is working, we strongly advise against using d.py with our library.

> Additionally, we will not give help for any issue resulting from using d.py with our library except of “Do not use discord.py”.

The developers of the [Interactions](https://discord-interactions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) library discourage the use of discord.py which makes it unlikely they want to work with them.

For the forseeable future, it might be better to use discord.py because it is meant for discord. However, I feel that this comes down to personal preference but it would be better to choose only one of the two instead of both.

---

For more information on slash commands using discord.py,
[discord.Interaction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#interaction), [discord.app_commands.CommandTree](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.CommandTree), [discord.Client](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client)

Comment: I see! Thank you for the detailed explanation, I will think about this thoroughly =)

Comment: Interestingly enough, I actually decided to migrate to `Pycord` library. It's similar to `discord.py`, just with a bit more convenient code structure and it also allows usage of prefixed and slash commands at the same time. Thought maybe this will be useful for you too