# My bot won't listen to commands when using slash commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

It's saying no command was found when it's right there, I've tried to use on_message events too, but those aren't working either.

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-', Help_Command=help, intents=discord.Intents.all())
intents=discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents = intents)
activity = discord.Activity(type = discord.ActivityType.streaming, name="name", url = "twitch_url")
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)
bot.remove_command('help')
blue = discord.Color.from_rgb(0, 0, 200)
red = discord.Color.from_rgb(200, 0, 0)
green = discord.Color.from_rgb(0, 200, 0)
discord_blue = discord.Color.from_rgb(84, 102, 244)
guild_id= 1132535168247275600

@tree.command(name="sync", description="Make slash commands global.", guild=discord.Object(id=guild_id))
async def sync(int: discord.Interaction, member: discord.Member):
  await tree.sync()
  print('Command tree synced.')

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
  await ctx.send("hello")
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use both [client](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#client) and [bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot). You can only use one of them.

As of Python 3.11 and Discord.py 2.3.2, you can use both prefix commands and slash commands with [commands.Bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot). Credit: Rexy

If you choose to use [discord.Client](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#client),

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands

client = discord.Client(...)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)


@tree.command(name="mycommand")
async def command_callback(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(content="Hello World")
```

If you choose to use [commands.Bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot),

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(...)
tree = bot.tree

#  Same command code as discord.Client example
```

Note: you can still use events like [on_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_message) with app command trees.

You also have a problem with syncing. When putting your `sync` function inside a slash command, it won't get synced because that command itself hasn't been synced.

Instead, you should first put it in an [on_ready](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_ready) event before removing it and using the `sync` command. Or make a prefix sync command which would be able to be used on restart.

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.tree.sync()


@bot.command(name="sync", description="Sync the command tree.")
async def sync_callback(ctx):
    await bot.tree.sync()
    await ctx.reply(content="Synced!")
```

For more information on slash commands, see [discord.Interaction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#interaction), [app_commands.CommandTree](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.CommandTree).

More on [discord.Client](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#client), [commands.Bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot).

Also see [Difference between commands.bot and interactions.client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76348433/difference-between-commands-bot-and-interactions-client).

Comment: Well explained! One correction: with commands.Bot you can use prefix and slash commands in py 3.11 and discord.py 2.3.2 
I only know because I do it.

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: @Rexy That's new to me! I'll be sure to check that out

Comment: @sumnaah What do you not understand?

Comment: @Raymus i meant to reply to rexy on how he uses both

Comment: @Rexy how do you do that?

Comment: @sumnaah bot.tree.command() and bot.command() can be used together.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you want to sync with a tree command which will only be synced after you synced it. You created a paradox. Instead use a normal command or the on_ready() event to sync the commands.

Comment: it says client has no attribute tree?

Comment: @Raymus explained why that happens.